# Correct EDAC driver for Supermicro X10SLL-F

Tags: linux, supermicro, ecc

Prompted by Debian upgrade (stretch to buster), I've replaced mcelog with rasdaemon. I'm not sure whether things work as expected though. In `dmesg` I can find a message like this:

```
[    1.871662] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
```

However, `edac-utils` is less optimistic:

```
# edac-util -sv
edac-util: EDAC drivers loaded. No memory controllers found
```

and sure enough, there are no mc devices here:

```
# ls -l /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jul 21 20:15 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul 21 20:05 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/edac
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 21 20:05 uevent
```

There are no `edac` modules loaded at all into the kernel. In a desperate attempt, I've looped through the drivers available in the default kernel but without much of success. I've checked the [Supermicro](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X10SLL-F)'s website for this model but haven't found anything useful.

How do I go about finding whether it's supported at all?